# ¿las conexiones con DynamoDb es una app independiente de una web API .NET o están dentro de la misma web API?

Tags: c#, aws

Necesito desarrollar una aplicación `C#` que corra sobre `Amazon Web Services` y que acceda a una base de datos `DynamoDB` (Provista por Amazon).

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿Debo crear dos aplicaciones diferentes (una para acceder a `DynamoDB` y otra la `web api`) o una sola aplicación en la cual tengo la `web api` y dentro de ésta coloco los accesos a `DynamoDB`?
Gracias

Comment: A qué te refieres que corre en AWS? La vas a ejecutar en una Instancia EC2? Si es así no ha ninguna restricción para tu aplicación en cuanto a diseño, lo haces a tu gusto. Te sugiero separar el acceso a datos del resto del código, de forma que sea más fácil de mantener en el tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es algo tarde la respuesta, pero aqui van mis dos centavos.

No se entiende muy bien lo que deseas hacer, pero me da la impresión que quieres desarrollar una aplicación que por un lado exponga una API, y por el otro guarde los resultados en DynamoDB. Si es así, se puede construir en una sola solución con tres capas; donde lo único que cambiaría respecto a si usaras otro motor de persistencia, es que en vez de comunicarte con SQL Server/MySQL/Oracle/etc; lo harás contra la API de DynamoDB.